# Discontinuity Vs Not continuity.

Tags: real-analysis

What is difference between Discontinuous and not continuous of a function $f$ at some point $x=a?$ I think there is not difference between the two. Is there some difference between these two related to limit points of the domain of the function $f?$ Please describe if there is some difference between Discontinuous and not continuous at some point. Thanks!

Comment: It's exactly the same.

Comment: i read somewhere like if a is a limit point of the domain and f is not defined at a then f is said to be discontinuous but not as not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

These are the same, but there are several kind of discontinuities. Maybe that's the distinction you wanted to make.
See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities

Answer (score 0):

Many authors reserve the word **discontinuous** to be used only for points where the function is *defined* (and likewise for **continuous**, but that's obvious). In that case there is a difference: at a point which is not in the domain, the function can be said to be both "not continuous" and "not discontinuous"! See the answers here: [Is function $f:\mathbb C-\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb C$ prescribed by $z\rightarrow \large \frac{1}{z}$ by definition discontinuous at $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087623/is-function-f-mathbb-c-0-rightarrow-mathbb-c-prescribed-by-z-rightarrow)